# i have a multiple checkbox list (mat-select angular) which i use to add roles to a user. It works but the role of the user have to be checked

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material

For example User "A" has a role of ADMIN and i want to add a role of AGENT so when i click on the button "add roles"  and open the checkbox list i want to have the role AGENT checked before starting adding any role. Any help please!

[[[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w7BD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VerD7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBzEz.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The selection is bound to ngModel. Whatever you want to select, you have to set this selection to the ngModel value.

Example:

```
 <mat-select [(ngModel)]="mySelectedElements" multiple>
    <mat-option value="A">A</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="B">B</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="C">C</mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

With ts

```
this.mySelectedElements = ['A', 'C']; // will preselelect first and last option
```